# Unable to add data to InfluxDB using dict type as field entry

Tags: python, grafana, influxdb

I'm not able to spot my mistake adding data to my InfluxDB by using the following scheme:

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
import datetime
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import ASYNCHRONOUS

client_db = InfluxDBClient(url=f"http://{ip}:{port_db}", token=token, org=org)
write_api = client_db.write_api(write_options=ASYNCHRONOUS)

data = {
          "measurement": "title",
          "time": datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f"),
          "fields": db_dict    
       }    
      
write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=data)
```

where db_dict is a dictionary with multiple key:value entries. I don't receive any error but my DB remains without entries. It worked out fine before following this pattern - not this time. I also tried out varying with a time offset but didn't solve the problem. Any ideas whats the issue here? Thankful for every hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving your `time` field as a python Datetime or converting it to a Unix timestamp (in nanoseconds) instead of formatting it as a string.